# Is there a reason why in C++20 std::vector operator == does not work for vectors with different allocators?

Tags: c++, c++20, allocator, c++-concepts

Note:

I know usual reasons are possible: nobody thought of it/wrote paper/WG21 did not think it is worth the effort, I am more interested in technical problems that prevent potential implementation than in the value of utility of this functionality.

I always found it weird that this does not [work](https://godbolt.org/z/qd6bA7)(even before concepts, since we could use enable_if)

```
#include <vector>
#include  <boost/align/aligned_allocator.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<int,64>> b{1,2,3};
    return a==b;
}
```

Reason is that allocators do not affect the values stored in the container(I understand that values could be using their address in the operator ==, I am talking about "normal" types).

So my question is:
if we wanted to do it with C++20 concepts could we introduce this functionality without breaking any existing code?

Comment: Perhaps `a.size() == b.size() and std::equal(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin())` ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux actually now C++ has 4 iter version of equal, but yes I did know that I could use std::equal,  I was just wondering about ==

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't any technical problems. It's certainly trivial to implement:

```
template <std::equality_comparable T, typename A1, typename A2>
bool operator==(std::vector<T, A1> const& lhs, std::vector<T, A2> const& rhs) {
    return std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
}
```

And then why stop at allocators? Why can't I compare a `vector<int>` to a `vector<long>`?

[P0805](https://wg21.link/p0805) is the proposal for widening the comparison set to allow comparing both mixed-type and mixed-allocator containers. It was approved for C++20, but didn't make the cut and still needs some work to fit in with the new C++20 concepts (notably, `equality_comparable_with` requires `common_reference`: what's the common reference between two `vector`s having different allocators?)

---

In the meantime, `std::ranges::equal(v1, v2)` works for heterogeneous vectors.

Comment: nice answer and paper is nice, but for the record I disagree with P0805 on comparing std::arrays of different size, it just seems very error prone to me.